# Can open-circuit voltage be treated as voltage to find power dissipated?

Tags: voltage

[image]

Can open-circuit voltage be treated as voltage to find power dissipated?
I combined all the resistors (including `Vlamp`) to get one resistor of 40/6 Ohms (Correct me if I'm wrong). Using Ohm's law to find the current doesn't work since I don't know the voltage, Thus the title. I don't think so but I wasn't taught this in detail and Googling doesn't benefit since Wikipedia has a page

I already figured out that:
`Battery has open circuit voltage of 4V`
`R1 = 5 Ohms`
`R2 = 5 Ohms`
`k = 0.2A/V`
`When lamp on and Vlamp = 2V, Rbat = 10 Ohms`

The lamp turns on if the voltage across the lamp is greater than 2V. When the lamp is on it has an internal resistance of 10 Ohms, and when it is off it acts like an open circuit.
[image: The lamp turns on if the voltage across the lamp is greater than 2V. When the lamp is on it has an internal resistance of 10 Ohms, and when it is off it acts like an open circuit.]

This is what I calculated:

[image]

I'm getting `Ilamp` as 1/5, still trying to see how that will help...
**EDIT:**
My answer has been suggested as a duplicate.
Is it the same question? NO.
Is it the same answer? NO.

The only thing that is the same is the circuit, any objections?

Comment: What is R_lamp?

Comment: `R_lamp` is 2V when the lamp is on, @W5VO .

Comment: no - **V**_lamp is 2V. W5VO is asking about **R**_lamp.

Comment: 10 Ohms then, @brhans .

Comment: So both Rbat and Rlamp are 10-ohms?

Comment: Miscalculated, it's `40/6` instead if `45/7`

Comment: Yes @brhans , They are both 10 Ohms

Comment: What are you actually supposed to calculate here?

Comment: You need to show your analysis. This the second question you've asked today, and there's been no input from you for either of them.

Comment: Here's my analysis, @Chu .

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My question is edited

Comment: That's not an analysis.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested last night?  You know the voltage over R2 and the lightbulb, so you know current over them and therefore R1.  These online answer forms are pretty useless for showing work, and if you don't show your work, we can't tell you where you're going wrong, only if you're right or wrong.  What have you calculated for \$I_{Lamp}, V_{R2}, I_{R2}, I_{R1}, V_{R1}?\$.  Ooops!  Once we calculated all that, we know \$V_{Bat}\$!  It's not worth trying to avoid work at the beginner level by trying to find an intuitive way to view the circuit.  Just draw a diagram, start solving.

Comment: Once you've gotten that far, show your work and we can help if necessary with the rest.  Showing your work should look something like \$Z=X*Y=5*4=20\$ for each variable you solve for, so we can see the formula, then the inserted values, and your solution.  You can whip that circuit image into an image editor and write on to it for clarity if you wish, but when I'm in a course, there's something to be said for pen and paper.

Comment: There is an edit button at the bottom of your question by the way, you don't need to delete and re ask.  As long as no one has written an actual answer yet, it's perfectly fine to keep editing your question for greater accuracy or a better response.  When you're showing your work, you don't need to use \$MathJax\$ for fancy looking variable names like \$R_2\$.  If typing all of your formulas out is very hard for you, Showing your work, neatly written, in a sharp photograph of a notebook page is OK.

Comment: This is actually a new question, not a duplicate.  I think I have it solved but I need you to participate more so I can post my answer and one of the engineers can tell me if I'm right.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! Though I don't need help anymore, No one has ever helped me out like this. It means a lot to me!